# Shareable By Editors Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Google App Script allows a user to change the "Shareable by Editors" setting on a google document via this [call](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#isShareableByEditors%28%29).

```
isShareableByEditors(false)
```

Does the same call exist using the Google Drive SDK/API? I would be using python to interact with these documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

It is possible. The Google Drive SDK calls the property of file

```
 writersCanShare
```

It acts the same as the Google App Script.